# Dynamic SQL using Snowflake SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, sql, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to be able to update rows of data in a set list of tables for certain columns within those tables.

Basically something like this;

```
TABLE_NAME    COL1     
TABLE1        NAME     
TABLE2        ADDRESS 

select * from TABLE1;

Aidan

Select * from TABLE2;

Ireland
```

So something like the query below as a stored procedure that would gather all the tables and columns to be altered and update the records accordingly.

`update $TABLE_NAME set $COL1 ='*' where ID in (select ID FROM EXTERNAL_TABLE)`

Any help greatly appreciated.

Tried messing around with this sample but got nowhere when I try build on it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATA_MASKING("P_TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
// Define query String
var sql_command = "UPDATE " + P_TABLE_NAME + " SET IND_ADDR1 = NULL;"

//Prepare SQL statement

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});

//Execute SQL Statement   
var rs = stmt.execute();
return ''Table truncated successfully.''

';


call PERSISTENT_DATA_MASKING('TEST_TABLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

The Proc you had given works. Just needs few amends which you must have been able to do. So, not sure what exactly is the question.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATA_MASKING("P_TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216), "P_COLUMN_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
// Define query String
var sql_command = "UPDATE " + P_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + P_COLUMN_NAME + " = ''x'';"

//Prepare SQL statement

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});

//Execute SQL Statement   
var rs = stmt.execute();
return ''successful''

';
CALL DATA_MASKING('SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME');
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No I couldn't get the syntax correct but thank you for the help. 

What I need to be able to do is pass a few tables and a few columns through the same procedure call is something like that possible as I don't want to write a new line of code every time a new table or column needs to be added.